# SilkTest : Navigate to Browser Instance1

Tags: silktest

I login as User1 from Browser- instance1, then login as User2 from same browser Instance2, how can I go back to Browser- instance1? 
Browser: IE6-7

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Open Agent, you should be able to access the windows with `Desktop.Find("//BrowserApplication[1]")` and `Desktop.Find("//BrowserApplication[2]")`.

Alternatively, if the browsers have distinct captions, you can use `Desktop.Find("//BrowserApplication[@caption='Distinct Caption']")`